# Make text and icon stick together on responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive, nowrap

I'm using this for my top bar text

`<i class="fa fa-envelope" style="margin: 0 4px"></i>info@email.com`

but in responsive design the envelope icon gets split from the mail text. I am trying to stick them together with no luck.

I have tried this but nothing

S Overflow

Comment: Try adding a working snippet so that we can better understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for `white-space: nowrap;`
try adding the parent container of the icon and text that CSS class.

[W3S link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) for more information